# Primeface3.5 picklist ontransfer item background hilight in IE8 remains

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using primefaces3.5 picklist my problem is with IE8,whenever I try to select an item in   source item list then click on move button it moves to the target list but the highlight of  the item is not going,rather it should go away. is there any workaround for this ? it would be   helpful.

Comment: I tested it with PF 3.5 and IE 10 in 7 and 8 compatibility modes and can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: it is only reproducable in bootstrap them.

Comment: I don't understand your issue then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same problem with Primefaces 4
There is a problem with theme.css from bootstrap-1.0.10.jar

Remove or comment

```
filter:progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff0088cc', endColorstr='#ff0077b3', GradientType=0);
```

From **.ui-state-highlight,.ui-widget-content .ui-state-highlight,.ui-widget-header .ui-state-highlight** fix the problem.